# Calculate Adobe XD text size and implement in Flutter text widget

Tags: flutter, dart, adobe-xd

I have a design in `adobe xd` where a `text` size is `40px` according to `adobe xd` but if i use this `40px` in flutter `text` widget then it shows a big difference. So do i how calculate the `adobe xd` `text` size pixel in flutter `text` widget?